# Search for common datetime values in different dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I'm working on a python script where I have to find de common datetimes between different dataframes.
The first frame (df_features) is a frame with data from features and datetime windows, where the index is the windownumber.

```
[index, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4,     Start,                   End]
[    1,       20,       1.5,       3,        1,  2020/04/05 11:05:15  2020/04/05  11:05:35]
```

So window 1 has a duration of start to end with a duration of 20 secs in each window.

My second dataframe (df_timestamps) is a frame with Timestamps and events.

```
[index, event, timestamp]
[ 1,    start rest, 2020-04-05 11:05:25]
```

Now i need to search in which window from dataframe1 the events of dataframe2 takes place. with the examples above you should get that the start of rest took place in window 1 because the timestamp 2020-04-05 11:05:25 is between 2020-04-05 11:05:15 and 2020-04-05 11:05:35.
I need to write a code that gives back these window indexes of al events. I hope you can help me with the example i gave above
I want something like: if datetime value in df_timestamps == datetimevalue in df_features than give back the index number of df_features.

```
mask = df_features['Start'][0]< df_k[0][0] & df_features['End']>df_k[0][128]
```

i thought i have to do something like above, but i didnt work

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please provide context with clear examples

Comment: *datetime* means date and time - in the first example you only have time, of which you say is a duration (which is again something slightly different). in the second example you claim to have a *timestamp* - which is unclear. what is it? a date? a time? datetime?  in which format/datatype? To answer this, more details and a [mre] are required.

Comment: so in the first dataframe i've got my feature values sorted in windows, where the column 'start' gives the begin of the window and de 'end' column gives the end, in datetime. So these are windows of 20 secs.
The second dataframe are also datetimes. These datetimes were written down in events when the measurement took place. So when there was a moment of rest at 2020/05/04 11:05:13, that event was noted. now i want to search in which windows of dataframe 1 the events of dataframe 2 took place. I hope its more clear now

Comment: could you add those info in to the question? also, concerning the relationship of the time windows and the timestamps, you don't care about the date, just the time?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have something like

```
import pandas as pd
df_features = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2020/04/05 11:05:15', '2020/04/05 11:19:15'],
                            'End':   ['2020/04/05 11:05:35', '2020/04/05 11:19:35']})

df_k = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2020-04-05 11:05:25']})
```

make sure everything is datetime dtype

```
df_features['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_features['Start'])
df_features['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df_features['End'])
df_k['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_k['timestamp'])
```

then the comparison for the first entry in the timestamp column can look like

```
# search in which window from dataframe1 the events of dataframe2 takes place
mask = (df_features['Start'] < df_k['timestamp'].iloc[0]) & (df_features['End'] > df_k['timestamp'].iloc[0])

# df_features[mask]
#                 Start                 End
# 0 2020-04-05 11:05:15 2020-04-05 11:05:35
```